# Magento 2 - change default category product grid settings

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, phtml

Magento 2 has four products displayed per row in the category view (grid) by default.

How can i change that so it shows 9 products per page `(3x3)` in grid view? Currently it shows 9 products, but `4x2 + 1` product at third row.

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yh0c03fb/) with current and wanted grid setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layout of Magento 2 is responsive layout, if you want to set 3 products for per row you need to use style sheet to do this.

Comment: Thanks. Do i have to edit view.xml also? When i changed less the images get blurry? I have also cleaned cache, but new images are not generated.

Comment: I also edited view.xml to generate new images and their width's - thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

to change Products displayed per row in magento2 please follow below steps

Go To below path

```
app\design\frontend\Magento\<your Theme>\Magento_Catalog\web\css\source\module\_listings.less
```

Go to Line No. 324 (approx) and comment code (if you extended LUMA theme)

```
/*  .page-products .products-grid .product-item {
        width: 24.439%;
        margin-left: calc(~"(100% - 4 * 24.439%) / 3");
        padding: 0;
        &:nth-child(4n+1) {
            margin-left: 0;
        }
    }*/
```